# Changing numpy array size based on data

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataset as a dataframe.

```
BinSize   Data
   5       x1
   5       x2
   10      x3
   10      x4
```

I am looking to create data to only have a bin size of '5'. So I basically, want to divide second column by first column and multiply by 5. I am presently doing it via a 'for' loop, and assigning a new numpy array. Wondering if there is an efficient way

```
BinSize    Data
   5         x1
   5         x2
   5         x3*5/10
   5         x3*5/10
   5         x4*5/10
   5         x4*5/10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you should be able to operate on the dataframe directly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'BinSize': [5, 5, 10, 10], 'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['Data'] = (df['Data'] /df['BinSize']) * 5
```

EDIT:

In the interest of posting something a little more useful than above, here it is in one line but a) it only works if the starting binsize is a multiple of 5 and b) it is long and difficult to read so what you have already is probably preferable. I couldnt see anything in the pandas library that could be used.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BinSize': [5, 5, 15, 10], 'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df = [pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(np.tile([binsize * 5 / binsize,
                                      data * 5 / binsize],
                                     (int(binsize / 5), 1)),
                             columns=['BinSize', 'Data']) for data, binsize in zip(df['Data'], df['BinSize']))][0]
```

Comment: I need a new data frame, with six rows.